# Employee Shift ASP.NET Scheduler (WeekDays/Time)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I'm searching for a control of even how to implement this in ASP.NET WebForms, the recruitment is A shift will be created with many periods and I need to display the Shift's Periods in a table format:

[image: Dummy Schedule]

Comment: @AntonioBakula Solved, Sorry

Comment: np, I just found that little mistake funny :) btw. take a look at telerik Rad Scheduler control : http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/scheduler.aspx

Comment: You can do this on reporting services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some options:

- This used to be free, but now is paid: http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Calendar/WorkWeekView.aspx

  - See if the still-free version works for you http://www.daypilot.org/daypilot-lite.html

.

- Another paid option http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/timelineview/defaultcs.aspx (click 'work week' on the right of the blue calendar header)

.

- Check the suggestions in http://forums.asp.net/t/1296364.aspx

.

- Maybe try a pure jQuery plugin, and integrate it with ASP.NET webforms using your own client code. The most popular is http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ (demo at http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/theme.html )

  - If you don't like the default behaviour, try any of the forks mentioned in https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490 and https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490

.

- If you go down the jQuery path, there are VERY interesting options listed in http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-or-non-jquery-calendar-schedulers/ and http://www.web-delicious.com/4-best-javascript-jquery-event-calendar-planner-scheduler/

Comment: Telerik Scheduler has recurring event which you can choose which day you want this event to be repeated, I'll check if this will cover my requirement, Thanks.

Comment: Their "work week" view I mentioned in my reply is very close to what toyu want too, except the vertical and horizontal axes are inverted.